# If JSON is null - PHP

Tags: php, json, if-statement, null, response

This is my complete script. What I want to do is to set $bg to let's say "none.jpg" if the response from the URL is "null". If the response is something else, set $bg as I'm already doing in this script.

```
$backgroundURL = 'http://api.fanart.tv/webservice/artist/a93e666f14a34d979b3e3617eab2f340/6b1cf581-17a9-42c3-927b-d1e2797b1695/json/artistbackground/1/1';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $backgroundURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; curl)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json  = json_decode($json);
$first = current($json);

$bg    = $first->artistbackground[0]->url;
```

Comment: Can you provide json string?

Comment: You probably need: `if($json === '"null"'){`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
if('null'==$json){
  echo 'Nothing here!';   
} else {
  echo 'Yep, found it!';
}
```

If the result really contains the literal *string* "null" as you state, then you must compare that that string, not to the language construct `NULL`.

---

Considering your comments below I tested your script and added a conditional as written above.

```
<?php
$backgroundURL = 'http://api.fanart.tv/webservice/artist/a93e666f14a34d979b3e3617eab2f340/6b1cf581-17a9-42c3-927b-d1e2797b1695/json/artistbackground/1/1';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $backgroundURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; curl)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ('null'==$json) {
  echo "reply is 'null'\n";
} else {
  echo "reply is NOT 'null'\n";
}
?>
```

The output is as expected: `reply is 'null'`...

Comment: If it is a valid json response containing the string `null`, it is probably `"null"`, unless the OP has decoded it.

Comment: To nitpick, `NULL` is not really a language construct.

Comment: @jeroen True. I only answered to the question. I try not to interpret what I think what the OP might mean when there is a clear statement. If the question states something that is not the case, then the question should be changed.

Comment: @AmalMurali Ah, ok. Would you mind explaining what it is then?

Comment: @arkascha: I believe they are a [group of tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

Comment: @AmalMurali Hm, surprisingly `null` is featured as "predefined constant"... http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php Sounds odd to me...

Comment: It didn't do the trick for me, I'm afraid... Have a look at this JSON document, it returns "null". Even though I use your script example, it still returns "Yep, found it!". http://api.fanart.tv/webservice/artist/a93e666f14a34d979b3e3617eab2f340/6b1cf581-17a9-42c3-927b-d1e2797b1695/json/artistbackground/1/1

Comment: Then the contents of that variable is _not_ "null", as you stated in your question. So what _is_ it? Also please see the first comment to _this_ question posted by @jeroen.

Comment: Well what's the content of http://api.fanart.tv/webservice/artist/a93e666f14a34d979b3e3617eab2f340/6b1cf581-17a9-42c3-927b-d1e2797b1695/json/artistbackground/1/1 then?

Comment: A simple test with `wget` and `wireshark` shows that the server sends  content of type `application/json`, length 4, content 'null'. That does _not_ mean that the content of your _variable_ is `"null"`, as you stated. We have no idea what your variable contains, since you did not post how you fill that variable.

Comment: Ahaaa... Sorry for that. As I said, I'm a real newbie at this :) Is there any way to check for "null" from the document? Or in other words, do something if the response is null as it is in this example, and do something else when the response is different?

Comment: Sorry, but this leads in circles... You need to post how you retrieve the answer and how you process it. Otherwise we have to _guess_ which leads to discussions we see here...

Comment: @arkascha I've updated my original question with the complete script I'm using. Does this help you at all? :-) Sorry again for the newbie stuff :)

Comment: Cool! Works like a charm now. Thanks for the help on this! :-)